# "Vkcoin не имеет атрибута 'wss_url'" при использовании longPoll

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
from vkcoinapi import *
coin = VKCoin(key = 'Ключ', merchantId = ид)
coin.longPoll()
```

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'VKCoin' object has no attribute 'wss_url'

Comment: Эпоха закончилась, ВК коин не используется.

Comment: Не надо дублировать один и тот же вопрос. Чтобы добавить подробности в вопрос просто редактируйте существующий.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте другую обертку для библиотек API VK Coin - [vkcoin](https://pypi.org/project/vkcoin/).

Код будет выглядеть похоже:

```
import vkcoin

merchant = vkcoin.VKCoin(user_id=12345,key='xxxxxxxxxxx')
@merchant.payment_handler(handler_type='longpoll')
def your_handler(data):
    pass
```